# No Connectionstring Name "somename" could be found in app.config

Tags: c#, wpf

Connection string is in my app.config file but it gives me error that it could not found it in app.config file.Secondly if I try to access any key from my app.config file it give me error of object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image: My Windows Form]

[image: My app.config File]

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following, you need to have a reference to System.Configuration.dll

```
var connection = 
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CPOSentities"].ConnectionString;
```